# Need to retain a CFSocketRef?

Tags: objective-c, ios, retain, core-foundation

I am facing a problem: I have two view controllers, `viewController1`, and `viewController2`.
Here is the method I'm concerned about in `viewController1`:

```
-(void)msgToServer:(NSString*)identifier:(NSString *)_username{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|<END>", identifier, _username]; 
    CFDataRef messageData = (CFDataRef)[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CFSocketSendData(s, NULL, messageData, 0);
}
```

this method is working perfectly in `viewController1`.

Now I am calling this method from `viewController2`. I am passing two arguments, `identifier` and `_username`. It generates the string perfectly, but when it reaches the last line it misses the value of `s` -- which is a `CFSocketRef`. 
What should I do so that `s` will retain its value, even if I am in `viewController2`?

Code from `viewController2` which calls the above method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    WatchListViewController *watchListViewController = [[WatchListViewController alloc]init];
    [watchListViewController msgToServer:@"PREQ" :userName];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put the code from viewController2 where u are calling msgToServer

Comment: you may check now the viewController2 code here "WatchListViewController" is viewController1

Comment: Where did you create the `CFSocketRef` that's in `s`? Could you show that code please?

Comment: i am creating it in viewController1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to all who helped me well i solved this problem in this way:
when I push from viewController1 to `viewController2` i am passing two parameters "`username`" and "`s`" to `viewController2` and then I write this method in `viewController2`.

```
-(void)msgToServer:(NSString*)identifier:(NSString *)_username{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|<END>", identifier, _username]; 
    CFDataRef messageData = (CFDataRef)[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CFSocketSendData(s, NULL, messageData, 0);
}
```

then I am calling this method in the same view controller and it works perfectly. I think this is the only solution which i find. if any body can make it more efficient then you are welcome. :)

Comment: Socket reference can not be retained cz this this like some int type so its value can not be retained even you can not write retain in  its property so when we write assign in its value then we are unable to retain it. If we have to use it some where then we have to pass it as a parameter. thats the only way to retain its value.

Comment: No, that's wrong. What you were missing is the existence of CFRetain(), which generally does a retain on a CF(anything)Ref

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `retain` function of `NSObject`.

```
- (id)retain
```

[See in Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retain)

Also have a look to [Object Ownership and Disposal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW2) in Memory Management Programming Guide

**EDITED:**

Try with below code

You might have issue with function prototype,not with retaining.

use below 
`-(void)msgToServer:(NSString*)identifier withUsername:(NSString *)_username;`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    WatchListViewController *watchListViewController = [[WatchListViewController alloc]init];
    [watchListViewController msgToServer:@"PREQ" withUsername:userName];
}

-(void)msgToServer:(NSString*)identifier      withUsername:(NSString *)_username{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|<END>", identifier, _username]; 
    CFDataRef messageData = (CFDataRef)[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CFSocketSendData(s, NULL, messageData, 0);
}
```

Comment: u r absolutely right but retain is used just to retain objects. & "s" is a CFSocketRef. this is a referrence. we declare it like: CFSocketRef s; so how can we retain its value?

Comment: nops it works weell with methods which are in same class but when i call it from viewController2 then it misses the value of "s" & crashes on that line. now i think have to pass that value to viewController2 then have to send it back to viewController1.